# Proper way for child-classes to have common properties with different types

Tags: c#, json, interface, abstract-class

I have a JSON object that will be formatted as such:

```
{
"myNodes": [
    {
        "param1": 1,
        "param2": "myValue2a",
        "param3": {
            "myParam3param": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "param1": 1,
        "param2": "myValue2b",
        "param3": [
        {
            "myItemA": "abc",
            "myItemB": "def",
            "myItemC": "0"
        }]
    },
    {
        "param1": 1,
        "param2": "myValue2c",
        "param3": [
        {
            "myItemA": "ghi",
            "myItemB": "jkl",
            "myItemC": "0"
        }]
    }]
}
```

In C#, I'm wondering how to structure response objects to handle this.  I'm guessing I'll have some sort of parent class or interface that contains param1, param2, and param3.  However, param3 will need to be declared as type "object", and sometimes it will be an object w/ myParam3param, and other times it will be a list of things.  I'm also guessing that I should use child classes that determine what type param3 is.

Is this possible?  How should this be accomplished... an abstract class or interface?

Comment: If the datatypes and the number of properties are different then maybe you have 2 different classes.

Comment: But I'd like to say that myNodes is a List of type parentClass (whatever that may be... something that definitely has param1, param2, and param3).

Comment: Would you accept the value of the last 2 parameters to be null? If so, then you can have 1 class only.

Comment: Json.Net's JObject implements IDictionary. You can add to it anything with key/value(which can be another object), So you don't have to use a strict  model.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class ChildClasses
{
    [JsonProperty("myNodes")]
    public List<MyNode> MyNodes { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyNode
{
    [JsonProperty("param1")]
    public long Param1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("param2")]
    public string Param2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("param3")]
    public Param3Union Param3 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Param3Element
{
    [JsonProperty("myItemA")]
    public string MyItemA { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("myItemB")]
    public string MyItemB { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("myItemC")]
    public string MyItemC { get; set; }
}

public partial class PurpleParam3
{
    [JsonProperty("myParam3param")]
    public long MyParam3Param { get; set; }
}

public partial struct Param3Union
{
    public List<Param3Element> Param3ElementArray;
    public PurpleParam3 PurpleParam3;

    public bool IsNull => Param3ElementArray == null && PurpleParam3 == null;
}

public partial class ChildClasses
{
    public static ChildClasses FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChildClasses>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this ChildClasses self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters = {
            new Param3UnionConverter(),
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

internal class Param3UnionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(Param3Union) || t == typeof(Param3Union?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                var objectValue = serializer.Deserialize<PurpleParam3>(reader);
                return new Param3Union { PurpleParam3 = objectValue };
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                var arrayValue = serializer.Deserialize<List<Param3Element>>(reader);
                return new Param3Union { Param3ElementArray = arrayValue };
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type Param3Union");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = (Param3Union)untypedValue;
        if (value.Param3ElementArray != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Param3ElementArray); return;
        }
        if (value.PurpleParam3 != null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.PurpleParam3); return;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type Param3Union");
    }
}`
```

Comment: from json example `param3` has property `myParam3param`